# Customised Dojo Tree

Tags: dojo, tree

I am trying to develop dojo tree with style shown in image in below link. I am using dojo-release-1.10.2. I am using theme as 'claro'. I am not getting the connection lines which provide parent-child relation as shown in image in below link. Can anyone advice me , to the same style as shown in below link.

http://cdn.tripwiremagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/images/stories/Articles/dojo/tree.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tundra theme shows the grid lines by default, with the exception of the root node, if you want the grid lines for the root node with tndra you should override the tree.css changing the background-image to this.

```
.tundra .dijitTreeIsRoot {
    margin-left: 0;
    background-image: url('images/i.gif');
}
```

If you want to override the claro theme, you can try this, , but you want to copy the gif files to your app and load them from there instead of loading them from tundra.

```
.claro .dijitTreeNode {
  background-image : url('../tundra/images/i.gif');
  background-repeat : repeat-y;
}
/* left vertical line (grid) for all nodes */
.claro .dijitTreeIsLast {
    background: url('../tundra/images/i_half.gif') no-repeat;
}
.claro .dijitTreeExpandoLeaf, .dj_ie6 .claro .dijitTreeExpandoLeaf {
    background-image: url('../tundra/images/treeExpand_leaf.gif');
}
.claro .dijitTreeIsRoot {
    background-image : url('../tundra/images/i.gif');
}
```